# Stub repeated method calls for rake test

Tags: ruby, rake-test

For my project I use rake test for testing my libs. For example, I've got a method, like `connection.users.add_users(options)`

```
json_response = check_users(options) 
batch = nil
Timeout::timeout(30) do
  begin
    sleep 1            
    batch = connection.batches.find(json_response["batch_id"])
  end while batch.state !="completed"
end
connection.users.add_users(batch.target_id, options)
```

So, first I make an HTTP request to my service, then I get the response (batch_id), loop until the batch is finished, then make another request and return the response.

Usually, in specs I do

```
let(:connection){setup_test_connection('{"batch_id": 344235}', '202')}
```

Which will stub `connection`'s response, but in the case of this method it stubs only the first call and then tries to make a real request to my service and so I get an error (timeout because the service is actually down at that time).

Is there any way to stub every possible call of `connection`'s class methods?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how do you actually stub your calls?

Comment: i try to do: @mock = MiniTest::Mock.new and then @mock.expect(:find, 42)   - like this

Comment: I meant how exactly do you stub your `connection` calls? It's not clear from your question. What does the `setup_test_connection` do?

Comment: method setup_test_connection  creates new    Telescope::Connection.new obj + do some stubs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out.

I should have used stubs to fake inside requests like this:

```
connection.servers.stubs(:schedule_create).returns({"batch_id" => 235234})
```